# Looping to subset dataframe by timestamps at the minute scale in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe that I am trying to subset into smaller dataframes by timestamps, all the way down to the minute scale. Let's say we have the following dummy dataset:

```
> mydata
           date id
1 3/29/17 18:16  A
2 3/30/17 18:05  B
3 3/30/17 18:16  C
4 3/30/17 18:16  D
```

I want to run a loop to sort and create mini dataframes by their timestamp on the scale of minutes, like this:

```
> mydata1
           date id
2 3/29/17 18:16  B

>mydata2
           date id
4 3/30/17 18:05  D

> mydata3
           date id
5 3/30/17 18:16  E
6 3/30/17 18:16  F
```

(I do plan on merging dataframes later so that all ids are present)

What is the most efficient want to do this in R? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `split` function and divide your `data.frame` based on `date` column. Since, `date` column in your `data.frame` is precise up to minute only, hence `split` will work. It will return list of data frames.

```
listDfs <- split(mydata, mydata$date)
listDfs
# $`3/29/17 18:16`
# date id
# 1 3/29/17 18:16  A
# 
# $`3/30/17 18:05`
# date id
# 2 3/30/17 18:05  B
# 
# $`3/30/17 18:16`
# date id
# 3 3/30/17 18:16  C
# 4 3/30/17 18:16  D
```

Another option (I'll say, ***preferred option*** ) is to group on `date` and arrange data accordingly. You can add a column for data frame number (if that helps). `dplyr::group_indices` can be used to specify a unique number for each group. A solution using `dplyr` and `lubridate` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

mydata %>% mutate(date = mdy_hm(date)) %>%
  mutate(df_num = group_indices(., date)) %>%
  group_by(df_num) %>%
  select(df_num, date, id)

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# # Groups: df_num [3]
# df_num date                id   
# <int> <dttm>              <chr>
# 1      1 2017-03-29 18:16:00 A    
# 2      2 2017-03-30 18:05:00 B    
# 3      3 2017-03-30 18:16:00 C    
# 4      3 2017-03-30 18:16:00 D
```

**Data:**

```
mydata <- read.table(text = 
"date id
1 '3/29/17 18:16'  A
2 '3/30/17 18:05'  B
3 '3/30/17 18:16'  C
4 '3/30/17 18:16'  D",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```